# Plant outside Ellora caves

Tags: identification

The below plant is in a garden outside the Ellora caves near Aurangabad, India.  It grows a couple feet tall with the flowers about an inch in size.  The fleshy stems are a little smaller than a quarter inch.
[image][image][image]

Answer (score 2):

By chance, [same plant found](http://www.vfindme.com/gardimages/pedil.jpg) in the Bahamas, New Providence Island, Ardastra Gardens, marked as *Pedilanthus tithymaloides*. I think @Brenn has this one.

Answer (score 1):

Closest I've been able to get is Euphorbia antisyphilitica, [upright segmented pink flower succulent](http://www.cactusconservation.org/CCI/cp/cp/Euphorbia_antisyphilitica.html).

Comment: Or perhaps Euphorbia tithymaloides: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euphorbia_tithymaloides